# Measure the size of a box or object on a fixed size platform

Tags: vb.net, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I have a web cam mounted over a table.  I know the exact size/measurements of the table and it won't change.

I want to be able to place a box or similar object onto the table, and then determine the size/dimensions of the item I just placed on the table.

Any tips or ideas on how I could do this ?

I tried using a 3d computer vision camera, but the environmental conditions required are to hard to achieve in the real world, and at best the measure measurement it was returned where random, and never consistent. If anybody knows of a good CV solution that is solid and robust that might also do the trick. (perhaps I just bought a crap solution)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it with OpenCV they have an sdk which i worked with a long time ago, check this: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/

Get "Emgu CV" the .Net wrapper here: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page